# Rubyrep 2.0.0 installation not working postgre 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I tried to install rubyrep following their instructions on their website and the the files are not running for installation. I have the latest JVM and on Windows 7. The application I am using is using POSTGRE 9.3.

I was running the batch file generated from the folder rubyrep.bat or is there a way to run the installation ?

Can someone guide me or give me tip on troubleshooting this problem even though the installation is straight forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line change into the directory where you have extracted the rubyrep zip file. You then just run `rubyrep` **NOT** `rubyrep.bat` as shown in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mika571, but the installation is now giving this error. I have installed jre 1.7 and even the latest java version, but the same error                   Cannot find class org/jruby/Main.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jruby/Mai
n : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:926)

Comment: It is even now saying can not find Java 1.5 or higher.  Any idea ?

Comment: I would confirm that java is installed correctly, this can be done via [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml)

Comment: I have uninstall and installed it and the version is even 1.8 after I decided not  to use 1.7. I have used the java for other application and is working.  java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: I reboot the machine and is now working. Last question, where would i write the code for replication, it is just coming up as command prompt.  Cheers

Comment: The settings go in your configuration file, you can generate one using `rubyrep generate myrubyrep.conf` and edit it with the settings you need then run `rubyrep replicate -c myrubyrep.conf` to start replication. See the [tutorial](http://www.rubyrep.org/replication.html) for more details

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for clarification.